# Why is "print into console" much faster than ".text into label "

Tags: ios, console, uilabel, swift3

I´m trying to display the cadence and pace data of `CMPedometer`. When I run the application with my phone attached, it writes the output of the data immediately through the `print("...")` function into the console, but takes multiple turns until it displays the data in the `UILabel`.
How can I get the data as fast as possible so I can use them?

Best, Zack

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let pedometer = CMPedometer()
    @IBOutlet weak var paceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cadenceLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard CMPedometer.isCadenceAvailable() && CMPedometer.isPaceAvailable() else{
            print("Pace and cadence data are not available")
            return
        }         
        let oneWeekAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -(7 * 24 * 60 * 60))
        pedometer.startUpdates(from: oneWeekAgo as Date) {data, error in
            guard let pData = data , error == nil else{
                return
            }
            //The current pace of the user, measured in seconds per meter. (1 step = 83cm?)
            if let pace = pData.currentPace{
                print("Pace = \(pace)")
                self.paceLabel.text = "Pace = \(round(Double(pace))*10/10)"
            }
            //The rate at which steps are taken, measured in steps per second.
            if let cadence = pData.currentCadence{
                self.cadenceLabel.text = "Cadence = \(cadence))"
                print("Cadence = \(cadence)")
            }
        }// -----------------oneWeekAgo        
    }// -----------------ViewDidLoad

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}//-------------------- UIViewController
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple turns?"

Comment: it prints multiple data outputs on my console like: Pace = 0.2812560419071308
Cadence = 2.879265785217285
Pace = 0.2812560419071308
Cadence = 2.879265785217285 and after about a minute it show on the label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update block is called on a background thread and you need to update your UI on the main thread.  Wrap the UI update calls in a dispatch back to the main thread:

```
Dispatch.main.async {
    //The current pace of the user, measured in seconds per meter. (1 step = 83cm?)
    if let pace = pData.currentPace{
        print("Pace = \(pace)")
        self.paceLabel.text = "Pace = \(round(Double(pace))*10/10)"
    }

    //The rate at which steps are taken, measured in steps per second.
    if let cadence = pData.currentCadence{
        self.cadenceLabel.text = "Cadence = \(cadence))"
            print("Cadence = \(cadence)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. hmm, seems like I need to do my homework on Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: found this useful link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1